# C#: XPath to select node with attribute containing a substring?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xpath, c#-2.0

Could I use XPath to select country node whose code containing UK?

```
<country-list>
  <Country code="TW,UK,MY" />
  <Country code="US,CA,MX" />
  <Country code="IN,PR,VI,IR" />
  <Country code="Others" /> 
</country-list>
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just curious why you accepted the answer when the answer didn't actually solve your problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try the `contains()` XPath function.

Something like:

```
/Country[fn:contains(@code, "UK")]
```

A quick Google search turns up details on XPath functions:
http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp

Comment: Hello, I meet this error:
[System.Xml.XPath.XPathException] = {"Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function."}

How could I get around it?

Comment: It's the 'fn:' namespace prefix. Try removing that.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xsl_functions.asp

Answer (score 3):

You need write it this way:

```
/country-list/Country[contains(@code,'UK')]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use Linq to XML - just as an idea

Something like this:

```
var countryElement = from country in countryElement.GetAttribute("code")
  where country.Value.Contains("UK")
  select countryElement;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, do something like

```
//Country[contains(@code, 'UK')]
```

which selected the first Country element