# Throw an exception: Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I ask a question about using XPath function [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781938/c-xpath-to-select-node-with-attribute-containing-a-substring)

But I meet a problem about this exception:

```
[System.Xml.XPath.XPathException] = {"Namespace Manager or XsltContext needed. This query has a prefix, variable, or user-defined function."}
```

The xml is as follows:

```
<x-config>
    <!--user location-->
    <x-list>
      <Country code="TW,UK,MY" />
      <Country code="US,CA,MX" />
      <Country code="IN,PR,VI,IR" />
      <Country code="Others" /> 
    </x-list>
```

And I use following code to retrieve matches:

```
XmlNode countryNode = cdnConfig.SelectSingleNode(
    string.Format("x-config/x-list/Country[fn:contains(@code, {0})]", countryCode)
);
```

I am a newbie of XPath. Could anybody elaborate more on this and give some workaround?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you post your code and a sample of your XML?

Comment: @Tuzo: I posted my code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/587864/xpath-and-c) should answer it.

In short: The `fn` prefix in your XPath expression is not recognized. You could supply an instance of `XmlNamespaceManager` to declare the prefix, but since .NET apparently doesn't have XPath 2.0 support, this won't help.

However, the `contains` function is already supported by XPath 1.0, so no need for XPath 2.0:

```
XmlNode countryNode = cdnConfig.SelectSingleNode(
    string.Format("x-config/x-list/Country[contains(@code, '{0}')]", countryCode)
);                                         ↑
```

Comment: Thanks, our legacy is still upon ASP.NET 2.0. Is there any library which can be downloaed to supply 2.0?