# Invalid Token when using XPath

Tags: xpath

I am making a modification to a web application using XPath, and when executed I get an error message - Invalid token!

This is basic what I am doing

```
public xmlNode GetSelection (SelectParams params, xmldocument docment)

{

    xpathstring = string.format("Name =\'{0}' Displaytag = \'{1}' Manadatory=\'{2}', params.Name, params.Displaytag, params.Manadatory);

    return document.selectsinglenode(xpathstring);

}
```

As you can see, I am making a string and setting values on the nodes I am trying to find against my xml document, and thus returning xml data that matches my parameters.

What is happening is that I am getting an xpathexeception error in Visual Studio and it says invalid token.

I do know that in the xml document that the parameters I am looking in the tags have double quotes, for example, Name="ABC". So, I thought the problem could be solved using an "\".

Can anyone help?

**Update from comments**

> In the Xml Document, the tag has
>   attributes where they are set as
>   Name="ABC" Displaytag="ATag"
>   Manadatory="true".

Comment: Bad question from one, who haven't accepted any of the past answers. Deserved -1.

Comment: If you need an XPath expression, you should provide a reduce input sample.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need:

```
//*[@Name="ABC"][@Displaytag="ATag"][@Manadatory="true"]
```

Or

```
//*[@Name="ABC" and @Displaytag="ATag" and @Manadatory="true"]
```

**Meaning**: *any element in the whole document having a `Name` attribute with "ABC" value, a `Displaytag` attribute with "ATag" value and a `Manadatory` attribute with "true" value.*

Comment: In the string format, would I need to construct it as follows: string.format("//*[@Name, {0}][@Displaytag, {1}][@Manadatory,{2}], params.Name, params.Displaytag, params.Manadatory); Would this work?

Comment: @Andy5: Why are you missing the `=` comparison operator?

Comment: I am basing on this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1787439/xpath-c-throw-an-exception-namespace-manager-or-xsltcontext-needed. if this wrong or if you have better way of this doing, then please show me what you mean?

Comment: @Andy5: The `attr, value` syntax used in that question was part of a call to the `contains(haystack, needle)` XPath function, not an equality check.

Answer (score 0):

The string passed as argument to `SelectSingleNode()` (BTW, the exact capitalization *is* important) is something like:

```
Name ='someName' Displaytag = 'someString' Manadatory='true'
```

This is *extremely different* than a syntactically legal XPath expression.

And the error message just reflects the fact that toxic food has been given to the XPath engine.

**Solution**: Do read at least a light XPath tutorial and then specify a correct XPath expression.

Comment: Whilst I do appreciate your comment on selectsinglenode(), but this is because I am typing it in and in the code it is correctly capitalised!

Comment: In the Xml Document, the tag has attributes where they are set as Name="ABC" Displaytag="ATag" Manadatory="true". So, I am not sure what you are not saying here? Is the "" the problem?

Comment: @Andy5: Read well... R E A D   .   .   .

Answer (score 0):

The string you are constructing is not a valid XPath expression. In fact, it is nothing like XPath at all.

Indeed, even if it were a valid XPath expression, constructing it this way by string concatenation is a very dangerous practice, because of the possibility of injection attacks. But I suspect that advice will fall on stony ground.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, how would you recommend protecting against injection attacks when defining an XPath from parameters?

Comment: Not all XPath APIs allow it, but when possible, use an XPath expression with params: //x[@key=$value] then from the calling environment, xpath.setParameter(value, 'fried chicken').